# Load controls with progressbar before Main Forms appear

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a MDI form on which I have a menu, Sidebar and somewhat around 50 More controls which makes my application interface very heavy. Also I am loading something around 500 user data which is also loading on my MDI form List box.

However all these process takes a lot of time to load, what I want to do is to load all the stuff just before displaying my MDI form.

Lets say, when I click on login, It should show a progress bar and when progress bar loads to end with all the configuration like "`User List Display`, `Loading of controls` and other `settings`": Then only MDI form should appear.

I have also gone through the DevExpress control:

1. Splash Screen: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument10826
2. Splash Screen video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFl6P9I6c5A

But this is proprietary.

Is there any control available with winforms so that I can accomplish it.

Like the way we use to see with Visual Studio, Photoshop and other softwares which are very heavily build.

Also, what would be the ideal way of doing this. I have read a lot about, `backgroundWorker` and `Threading`. Just need advice on what would be the best way as per you guys. And yes, the smartest way.

Comment: Set your form's `Visible = false` initially, create some `event` to notify that the loading work is done and handle the event to show your form.

Comment: But here with my MDI form I don't have `Visible` property. I have a property called `Opacity` but it does nothing.

Comment: What kind of `MDI form` are you using? `MDI form` is just a form with `IsMdiContainer = true`.

Comment: Yeah it is just `IsMdiContainer = true` thing only. But I don't have any visible property :/